# Is <apex:includescript> cumulative?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component

If I have two components (on a single page) that both reference the same JavaScript Static Resource using an  `<apex:includescript>` tag, will the script be included twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the same `<apex:includeScript />` tag multiple times, the JavaScript will only be included **once**. Don't forget to use `{!URLFOR($Resource.scriptJs)}` :-)

Best to load your libraries using `<apex:includeScript>` and then perform any component-specific invocations inside `<script>...</script>` tags.

Answer (score 6):

If I remember correctly this is the only reason why you would use `<apex:includescript>` to avoid having the same javascript file included twice via components

Otherwise you would just use `<script type='text/javascript' src='/resource/1233160164000/example_js'>`, because that would run a bit faster, and you can place your `<script>` at the bottom of the page (this way your page will load faster)

http://www.skrenta.com/2007/05/14_rules_for_fast_web_pages_by_1.html

**Edit: For the person that downvoted me**, this behaviour is actually described in the documentation: [apex:includeScript](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_includeScript.htm)

> For performance reasons, you may simply want to use a JavaScript tag
>   before your closing `<apex:page>` tag, rather than this component.